# How to define a list of QML object within a property with a "for" loop

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I have a QML object with a property `lods`. The property is a list of custom QML objects of type `LOD`.

Is there any way to define the content of the list with a `for` loop?

I was thinking about something like the following snippet; unfortunately, it doesn't work:

```
TileInfo {
    QtObject {
        id: __internal
        property var lodsValues: [
            156412, 78206, 39103, 19551, 9776, 4888, 2444, 1222,
            610.984, 305.492, 152.746, 76.373, 38.187, 19.093, 9.547,
            4.773, 2.387, 1.193, 0.596
        ]
    }
    lods: {
        var lod, levels = [], values = __internal.lodsValues
        for (var i=minZoomLevel;i<=maxZoomLevel;i++) {
            lod = LOD {
                "level": i
                "resolution": values[i]
            }
            levels.push(lod)
        }
        return levels
    }
}
```

Comment: Attach the code showing what you've tried

Comment: @Daenyth here you go, sorry about that

Comment: Why doesn't it work? What happens? Also, it would help if the example was complete so that we could run it ourselves.

Comment: hey @Mitch, this does not work as the qml syntax in the JS "for" loop is not supported. The real code has some heavy external dependencies, I am going to refactor the example to something comparable and runnable. Thanks for your feedback

Comment: What happens if you take away the `LOD` in `lod = LOD {`?

Comment: You mean by transforming it into a json? In that case the syntax is correct, but the compiler complains:
`Unable to assign QList<QObject*> to QQmlListProperty<QmlLOD>`

Comment: Try to add it in the `Component.onCompleted:{ for ....}`